# Why is WebClient DownloadData working on IIS Express but not on IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, iis-express, webclient

I have the following piece of code that is getting some data from a url.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
byte[] imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
```

The `url` variable is just a string but didn't work even if I make it a `Uri`.

While this is working fine when I'm running the site using IIS Express, when I load it via IIS the `webClient.DownloadData(url)` call is throwing an exception with message: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond IP:port", where IP and port are the values for the ip and port of the url I'm trying to access.

Also, if I go directly to that url using a browser it works fine. I turned the firewall completely off in case it was blocking the response from the external site but didn't make any difference.
Thanks

Comment: what is the url?

Comment: Have you tried it with a different URL, for example one at google?

Comment: Most obvious difference is that IIS Express runs under *your user account* whereas IIS will be running under other accounts (that may not have network credentials). Are you running on a home/unmanaged network or a work/managed network environment, where e.g. proxy and firewall rules may be implemented by other network devices?

Comment: I tried a URL pointing to Google but failed too.

Comment: I'm running it on a work network, behind a proxy. This is failing on my dev machine though

Comment: If you configure a new application pool in IIS to run using your user account and switch the application to run in that pool, does it work? If so, it confirms its account related. Then you can discuss with work how to get an appropriate service account which can reach the required destination(s).

Comment: You're right, changing the app pool identity to my user account worked, thanks! It was initially using 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' which I would expect it would be able to reach external addresses. At least now I have an idea as to why it's failing.

Comment: https://forums.iis.net/t/1232492.aspx?Failing+to+access+proxy+under+application+pool